# Как в функцию передать заранее неизвестное количество аргументов?

Tags: c#

Всем доброго времени суток. Решил написать простенькую программу по решению комбинаторных формул. Пользователь вводит все нужные данные, а программа выдает ему значение. Вот пришёл к реализации формулы перестановки с повторениями ,  а, как вы знаете, в знаменателе у нас имеется умножение факториалов чисел определителей. Так вот, как можно реализовать функцию , которая будет принимать неизвестное количество аргументов и высчитывать их факториал , а потом ещё перемножить это всё? Ну с умножением я как-то придумаю, а вот с передачей аргументво, что-то додумать не могу. Скриншота кода нет, т.к и нечего кидать.

Comment: используйте `params T[]` [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params)

Comment: Спасибо большое :)

Comment: Параметры однородные - значит, не надо усложнять, а использовать как аргумент массив или список

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для передачи в метод неизвестного количества параметров используется ключевое слово [`params`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params). Есть одно ограничение: после параметра с модификатором `params` нельзя указывать другие параметры.

Например, нахождение периметра фигур:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int p1 = Perimeter(10, 22, 17);
    int p2 = Perimeter(5, 2, 5, 2);
    int p3 = Perimeter(11, 11, 11, 11);

    Console.WriteLine($" P треугольника: {p1}\n P прямоугольника: {p2}\n P квадрата: {p3}");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static int Perimeter(params int[] sides)
{
    int perimeter = 0;
    foreach (var side in sides)
    {
        perimeter += side;
    }
    return perimeter;
}
```